# What causes the ErrorListener registered to a volley request to be triggered?

Tags: java, android, networking, android-volley, listener

This page says that we can register a Listener to a volley request for handling errors:
https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple

But it doesn't mention what kind of errors trigger this listener. Volley javadoc doesn't say anything about it either.

Specifically, will this listener be executed if a network error occurs.
I'm asking this because I've encountered an android code of the following form:

```
 private void method() {
    String URL = "";
    final int[] status_code = new int[1];
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    if (status_code[0] == 200) {
                        // do something
                    } else {
                        // display toast
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // display toast
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            status_code[0] = response.statusCode;
            return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
        }
    };
    // add request to queue
}
```

This code seems to suggest that the registered `ErrorListener` isn't called for network errors.

What are the conditions which cause the `ErrorListener` registered to a `Volley` request to be called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly privy to your entire code but poking through the Volley source code:

1. [Response.java](https://github.com/google/volley/blob/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/Response.java) takes in [VolleyError](https://github.com/google/volley/blob/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/VolleyError.java) object
2. [VolleyError](https://github.com/google/volley/blob/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/VolleyError.java) references [NetworkResponses](https://github.com/google/volley/blob/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/NetworkResponse.java) in its use.
3. Inspecting [NetworkResponses](https://github.com/google/volley/blob/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/NetworkResponse.java) deals with mainly HTTP status codes.
4. Also I'd note that [VolleyError](https://github.com/google/volley/blob/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/VolleyError.java) extends Exception.

So I would say the call back method is triggered when an Exception is thrown and [VolleyError](https://github.com/google/volley/blob/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/VolleyError.java) deals with HTTP status codes.

Answer (score 3):

The `ErrorListener` is triggered for `4xx` responses and `5xx` responses I cannot tell what happens though for the `3xx` redirection responses as it didn't happended to me.

Here is a list with all HTTP Response codes:
https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html

Answer (score 0):

I just call this statement

```
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
       Log.i(TAG, "onErrorResponse: " + context.getString(R.string.error_network_timeout));
    } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
      Log.i(TAG, "onErrorResponse: " + context.getString(R.string.error_server));
    } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
       //toast or log your error
    } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
      Log.i(TAG, "onErrorResponse: " + context.getString(R.string.parse_error));
    } else {
      Log.i(TAG, "onErrorResponse: Something went wrong ");
  }
```

You don't need to find error code